# Firebird dotnet batch inserts

Tags: c#, sql, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

can someone help me speed this up.
I have a dataset (from a csv file) called dsresult and I want to pump it into a firebird table.
Currently I am doing it 1 row at a time, but I would prefer to do this in batches of 500 rows.
I am using the firebird.net provider

```
string connectionString =    "ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database=MYDB.FDB";
string sql = "INSERT INTO POSTIN (NUMID, CHANGE, PLACENAME, BOXCODE, STRCODE, TOWN)  VALUES (@NUMID, @CHANGE, @PLACENAME, @BOXCODE, @STRCODE, @TOWN)";
FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(connectionString)
FbCommand command = new FbCommand(sql, conn);                   
foreach (DataRow r in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMID", r["NUMID"]);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHANGE", r["CHANGE"]);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLACENAME", r["PLACENAME"]);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BOXCODE", r["BOXCODE"]);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STRCODE", r["STRCODE"]);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOWN", r["TOWN"]);         
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

it takes aaaaaaaaaaages to run.
in delphi i would have just jused cachedupdates.
post 500 records at a time
and commit on the 500th

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting it all in a transaction?

Comment: no, any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird's wire protocol doesn't support sending more commands in one batch (and in one roundtrip). Probably best idea is to use [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html) (aka anonymous stored procedure) and send inserts there.

For example:

```
execute block
as
begin
  insert into ...;
  insert into ...;
  ...
end
```

and execute this.

BTW the `FbBatchExecution` will send one command a time as well.

Comment: Check the link and example I added to post.

Answer (score 5):

try something like this:

```
using(FbConnection c = new FbConnection(csb.ToString()))
{
    FbBatchExecution fbe = new FbBatchExecution(c);
    //loop through your commands here
    {
        fbe.SqlStatements.Add(cmd);
    }
    fbe.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Yes! try to add your code on a different method that returns a command  ready for execution and call that method on the loop

Answer (score 1):

You should only add the parameters once, and only change the values off them in the loop so something like:

create the parameters once:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@NUMID", FbDbType.Int)
....
```

in the loop do:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  command.Parameters["@NUMID"].Value = r["NUMID"];
  ....
}
```

this should really speed things up.